# Popes Benedict XVI or Pope St. John Paul II on the subject of the Antichrist and the end times?

Tags: catholicism, eschatology, john-paul-ii, benedict-xvi, antichrist

Has Pope Benedict XVI or Pope St. John Paul II written anything extensively (or even informally supported any author) on the subject of the Antichrist and the end times?

The [Catechism of the Catholic Church](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p1s2c2a7.htm) teaches the faithful about the Church's final combat:

> 675 Before Christ's second coming the Church must pass through a final trial that will shake the faith of many believers The persecution that accompanies her pilgrimage on earth will unveil the "mystery of iniquity" in the form of a religious deception offering men an apparent solution to their problems at the price of apostasy from the truth. The supreme religious deception is that of the Antichrist, a pseudo-messianism by which man glorifies himself in place of God and of his Messiah come in the flesh.
>
> 676 The Antichrist's deception already begins to take shape in the world every time the claim is made to realize within history that messianic hope which can only be realized beyond history through the eschatological judgment. The Church has rejected even modified forms of this falsification of the kingdom to come under the name of millenarianism, especially the "intrinsically perverse" political form of a secular messianism.
>
> 677 The Church will enter the glory of the kingdom only through this final Passover, when she will follow her Lord in his death and Resurrection. The kingdom will be fulfilled, then, not by a historic triumph of the Church through a progressive ascendancy, but only by God's victory over the final unleashing of evil, which will cause his Bride to come down from heaven. God's triumph over the revolt of evil will take the form of the Last Judgment after the final cosmic upheaval of this passing world.

Answer (score 2):

St. John Paul II once stated that we are now nearing the final confrontation.

> “We are now standing in the face of the greatest historical confrontation humanity has gone through. I do not think that wide circles of American society or wide circles of the Christian community realize this fully. We are now facing the final confrontation between the Church and the anti-Church, of the Gospel versus the anti-Gospel.
>
> “We must be prepared to undergo great trials in the not-too-distant future; trials that will require us to be ready to give up even our lives, and a total gift of self to Christ and for Christ. Through your prayers and mine, it is possible to alleviate this tribulation, but it is no longer possible to avert it. . . .How many times has the renewal of the Church been brought about in blood! It will not be different this time.” - [The Final Confrontation](https://www.thecatholicthing.org/2014/06/01/the-final-confrontation/)

Prophecy is usually recognized as true while the thing prophesized have run their course. The anti-church and anti-gospel of Pope John Paul II should be seen as something the against the Church and against the Gospels and not as a [counterfeit church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/66017/according-to-vatican-ii-catholicism-what-is-the-counterfeit-church-and-what-are) or a counterfeit gospel, although the Antichrist will no  doubt teach a false gospel of sorts.

> There are so many mistakes made today regarding the coming of Christ and the coming of the Antichrist by people like [Father Gobbi](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=4152), Michael H. Brown and the like that I simply offer the truth as offered by the early Church fathers.  So many false prophets have made the mistake of thinking that the seat of the Antichrist will be Rome or that the Church will become the seat of the Antichrist or that some future Holy Father will be the Antichrist and all of this is false.  The Jews must return and live in the Holy Land so that they can prepare the way for the Antichrist, for he and he alone will re-build the old Temple of David and this will be his seat and not Rome. - [Prophesies of the Antichrist](http://www.unitypublishing.com/prophecy/AntichristbySaints.htm)

**What have Popes said about Vladimir Soloviev?**

> Soloviev is a “Russian figure of extraordinary depth,” said St. John Paul II during his Angelus of July 30, 2000.
>
> He is “one of the greatest Russian Christian philosophers of the 19th and 20th centuries,” John Paul II said again in 2003 in a long message about Soloviev that the Holy Father sent to participants gathered to discuss this major figure on the 150th anniversary of his birth.
>
> In his Crossing the Threshold of Hope, John Paul II refers to Soloviev, and in his encyclical Fides et Ratio (Faith and Reason) he lists Soloviev as standing in a line of distinguished Christian philosophers.
>
> During a talk on Soloviev Cardinal Giacomo Biffi noted that the theologian-mystic was “cited approvingly by Cardinal Joseph Ratzinger.”
>
> Obviously, Soloviev has exceptional credentials...
>
> Although Soloviev died in 1900 as the door opened on the 20th century, Cardinal Biffi, a noted scholar of his works, pointed out his predictions of things that would happen in the 20th century are "astonishing" in their accuracy. - [Vladimir Soloviev, the Mystic Admired by Popes](http://www.ncregister.com/blog/joseph-pronechen/soloviev-the-mystic-admired-by-popes)

**Both Pope St. John Paul II and Pope Benedict XVI held in high esteem the Russian Philosopher** [Vladimir Solovyov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Solovyov_(philosopher)) and his book on the [Tale of the Anti-Christ](https://www.goodcatholicbooks.org/antichrist.html).

> In his Tale of the Antichrist, Vladimir Soloviev details a vision of how events might take place in the 20th century and into the 21st that usher in the Antichrist, and then how that monstrous person would act.
>
> Although Soloviev died in 1900 just as the 20th century began, he clearly showed himself a mystic, that’s along with him also being one of the greatest of philosopher-theologians named in league with the likes of Cardinal Newman — who a little earlier had given lectures on the times of the Antichrist — and even very close to Aquinas. St. John Paul II mentioned or specifically wrote about Soloviev several times. Benedict XVI, as Cardinal Ratzinger, referred to him.
>
> Soloviev was Russian Orthodox but, as John Paul II described him, a figure who “noted with great clarity the tragic division among Christians and the urgent need for their unity…” Soloviev worked for Eastern-Western unity under one religious head, the pope, and in person got Leo XIII’s blessing for his work. Four years before he died, **Soloviev became a member of the Eastern Rite Catholic Church**. - [Soloviev and His Tale of the Antichrist](http://m.ncregister.com/52444/b#.W4GAjvbn8dU)

**More on Vladimir Soloviev and the Antichrist and the end times follows here**:

> This Antichrist showed himself as a kindhearted humanitarian who appeared to love all forms of life. He was a vegetarian, was concerned about ecology, and was an ecumenist.
>
> “The twentieth century was the epoch of the last great wars and revolutions. The greatest of these wars had its distant cause in the movement of Pan Mongolism which originated in Japan as far back as the end of the nineteenth century.” China became heavily involved. Europe was invaded.
>
> Not long after the defeat of the invaders, the European states started to reorganize. The old institutions become extinct. Soloviev says: “Europe in the twenty-first century represented an alliance of more or less democratic nations — the United States of Europe.”
>
> Sounds a lot like the European Union.
>
> The Freemasons in the European Council have a hand in getting this man elected as president of the United States of Europe then giving him the next title of Roman Emperor — emperor of the world — as the Antichrist promised peace to the world, and food and prosperity under his rule. Governments around the world joined the United States of Europe.
>
> The Holy See was banished from Rome and made its way to St. Petersburg. But, Soloviev says, “In all the other countries, particularly in North America, the Catholic priesthood still had a good many representatives possessed of strong will, inexhaustible energy, and independent character, who welded together the Catholic Church into a closer unity than it had ever seen before…”
>
> **As those true to the Faith look to the Gospel and Church Fathers on the Antichrist** and see the nations led astray, the exposure of this wicked leader begins. Of course, he confronts them, but in a way not expected.
>
> He invites the true Christians to send representatives to meet with him where he has **transferred his imperial residence to Jerusalem** where he built luxurious palaces and a huge temple to unite all cults.
>
> Soloviev envisions the reaction of the Jews when they also learn this unmasked wicked imposter has led them astray from the real Messiah, and then the final say with Heaven’s answer. - [Soloviev and His Tale of the Antichrist](http://m.ncregister.com/52444/b#.W4HKFfbn8dV)

[image: Vladimir Solovyov]

[Vladimir Solovyov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Solovyov_(philosopher)) (January 28, 1853 - August 13, 1900)

Comment: Could you perhaps add a summary?  What exactly is your point?  The popes are right or the Catholic Church wrong or vice-versa or the antichrist came and went or what exactly?  Lots of verbiage, but sorry, missed your point.

Comment: "There are so many mistakes made today regarding the coming of Christ and the coming of the Antichrist by people like Father Gobbi"Can you clarify your statement to put credibility on this. Fr.
Gobbi's book had an imprimatur of three bishops plus the support of St.John Paul II not to mentioned clergy membership in thousands.

Comment: @jongricafort Imprimaturs can be retracted, sometimes with a fair amount of ecclesiastical pressure to do so.

Comment: "The anti-church and anti-gospel of Pope John Paul II should be seen as something the against the Church and against the Gospels and not as a counterfeit church or a counterfeit gospel,"(False statement) There is a counterfeit church and it is the church of the Schismatics headed by Schismatics Cardinals & Bishops as stated in 1John2:18-19. It is anti-gospel and anit-christ because they oppose the Mercy of God. Christ is Divine Mercy made flesh. Mercy is the heart of the gospel and the Anti-Christ are preaching the anti-gospel by opposing the Mercy of God.

Answer (score 1):

**Has Pope Benedict XVI or Pope St. John Paul II written anything extensively (or even informally supported any author) on the subject of the Antichrist and the end times?**

**Answer**

***YES!*** Pope Emeritus Benedict XVI had clearly prophesied the future of the Vatican II Church in line with CCC675, CCC676 & CCC6777.

**The future of Vatican II Church according to Pope Benedict XVI.**

> A restructured Church with far fewer members that is forced to let go of many places of worship it worked so hard to build over the centuries. A minority Catholic Church with little influence over political decisions, that is socially irrelevant, left humiliated and forced to “start over.”
>
> But a Church that will find itself again and be reborn a “simpler and more spiritual” entity thanks to this “enormous confusion.”
>
> “It will become small and will have to start pretty much all over again. It will no longer have use of the structures it built in its years of prosperity. The reduction in the number of faithful will lead to it losing an important part of its social privileges.” It will start off with small groups and movements and a minority that will make faith central to experience again. “It will be a more spiritual Church, and will not claim a political mandate flirting with the Right one minute and the Left the next. It will be poor and will become the Church of the destitute.”

*This was the prophesy made 40 years ago on the future of Christianity by a young Bavarian theologian, Joseph Ratzinger.*

http://www.lastampa.it/2013/02/18/vaticaninsider/ratzingers-forgotten-prophesy-on-the-future-of-the-church-h7DcrYFxNmAleoeDLkekzN/pagina.html

**This future predictions of the Vatican II Church is in line with the vision of Pope Leo XIII in 1884, when he narrated the conversation he heard between God and satan as follows:**

> The guttural voice, the voice of Satan in his pride, boasted to Our Lord: "I can destroy your Church."
>
> The gentle voice of Our Lord: "You can? Then go ahead and do so."
>
> Satan: "To do so, I need more time and more power."
>
> Our Lord: "How much time? How much power?
>
> Satan: "75 to 100 years, and a greater power over those who will give themselves over to my service."
>
> Our Lord: "You have the time, you will have the power. Do with them what you will."

This conversation affirmed the CCC675,CCC676 & CCC6777 too, as God by His Divine Providence will allow the Catholic Church to be destroy and also give satan more power or more room to penetrates the Church.

As we all know satan cannot destroy the Church founded by Jesus Christ as stated clearly on Matthew16:18:

> Thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church, and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it.  And behold I am with you all days, even to the consummation of the world.
> —Matt 16:18 (Douay-Rheims)

But, God in 1884 clearly gave satan by way of Divine Providence according to Mysterious Plan of God to allow satan to penetrate inside the Church as affirmed by Pope Paul VI ***"the smoke of satan has entered the Church"***. This is not to say that satan enter because he has power over Matthew16:18, satan enters by way of God's Providence.

Satan entering inside Vatican Church who had the powerful promised of Jesus Christ in Matthew16:18, is in parallel to God the Father Will on Jesus Christ persecutions, passion and death as the "Head of the Church" for it's glorious resurrection.

*The Vatican II Church as the Mystical Body of Christ must suffer the same too, as CCC675,CCC676 & CCC6777 teaches for it to emerge also into a Resurrected Glorious Church, as Pope Emeritus Benedict XVI prophesied as the future Church.*

Lastly, there is a **"counterfeit church"** and it will be set-up by satan himself, as **Arch.Fulton Sheen described it perfectly;**

**Words of Archbishop Fulton J. Sheen (1948):**

> “[Satan] will set up a counterfeit church which will be the ape of the [Catholic] Church… It will have all the notes and characteristics of the Church, but in reverse and emptied of its divine content.”
>
> “We are living in the days of the Apocalypse, the last days of our era. The two great forces – the Mystical Body of Christ and the Mystical Body of the anti-Christ – are beginning to draw battle lines for the catastrophic contest.”
>
> “The False prophet will have a religion without a cross. A religion without a world to come. A religion to destroy religions. There will be a counterfeit Church.”
>
> “Christ’s Church the Catholic Church will be one; and the false Prophet will create the other.” - Things Accelerate Toward the End – Prophecy of Archbishop Fulton Sheen

And **Fr.Stefano Gobbi's Blue Book** stated the actions of the "counterfeit church" in destroying the Vatican II Church in the following evil strategies:

> 1. the spread of errors which are being propagated,and are often taught by professors of theology in seminaries and in Catholic Schools and which thus acquire a certain character of credibility and legitimacy;
> 2. the open public rebellion against the authentic Magisterium of the Church, especially against that of the Pope, who has from Christ the duty of preserving the Whole Church in the truth of the Catholic Faith;
> 3. the bad example given by those Pastors, who have allowed themselves to be completely possessed by the spirit of the world and who become propagators of political and sociological ideologies, rather than messengers of Christ and of His Gospe, thus forgetting the mandate received from Him: "Go into the the whole world and preach the Gospel to every creature."

(*Fr.Gobbi's Book "To the Priest, Our Lady's Beloved Sons" message#420 page 682*)

[image]

***"The worldwide membership of the M.M.P. now numbers at least 400 cardinals and bishops, more than 100,000 priests, and millions of religious and faithful around the world."***

http://www.mmp-usa.net/history/

**In closing, Pope Benedict XVI gave clarity in his predictions of the future of the Church aligned with Church Doctrine in Catechism, while St. John Paul II gave the vision on the Final Confrontation of the Vatican II Church on the "counterfeit church the Anti-Church" in support of Archbishop Fulton Sheen prophecy on which it clearly stated that satan will set-up a counterfeit church that had entered into Vatican II Church in no less than Pope St. Paul VI describes it in his words "the smoke of satan had entered the Church".**

St. John Paul II was very close to Fr.Stefano Gobbi as he concelebrates a number of Holy Mass with St. John Paul II and gave the Marian Movement of Priests His Apostlic Blessings showing His support for the mission of the movement and it's messages.

The Three Bishops who gave IMPRIMATUR to Fr.Gobbi's book namely:

> El Cardenal Bernardino Echeverria Ruiz, OFM
>
> Cardinal Daoud’s Imprimatur for Arabic Edition
>
> Cardinal Wu’s Imprimatur for Chinese Edition

**IMPRIMATUR (Pronounced im-prim-AH-tur – Latin for “let it be printed.”)**

> Imprimatur is an official approval from the hierarchy of the Roman Catholic Church stating that a literary or similar work is totally free from error in all matters of faith and doctrine, and hence is acceptable reading for faithful Catholics. Approval is also sometimes indicated by the words Nihil Obstat which mean “nothing hinders”: there is no obstacle to publication. An imprimatur is not given lightly; it follows a thorough review process. It is usually printed on a page at or near the beginning of the work. The name and title of the official church censor or other ecclesiastical authority, and the date that permission was granted, always accompany either declaration.

Regarding prophecy of St. John Paul II on the Final Confrontation; here is what Mama Mary reveals to Fr.Gobbi:

**She Reveals Her Plan**

> In these messages, I also reveal to you my plan in its silent preparation, in its painful realization and in its victorious fulfillment. You are already about to reach the most painful and bloody conclusion of the purification which will take place in these years, before the great triumph of my Immaculate Heart in the coming to you of the glorious reign of Jesus.
>
> This is a plan which embraces this century. In 1917 at Fatima, I anticipated it, as in a prophetic announcement, at the moment when the great struggle between the Woman Clothed with the Sun and the Red Dragon became evident, a struggle which was to last throughout the whole century, as a proud challenge to God on the part of my Adversary, who was certain that he would succeed in destroying the Church and in bringing all humanity to a universal rejection of God.
>
> The Lord has granted him this space of time, because in the end the pride of the Red Dragon will be broken and conquered by the humility, the littleness, and the power of your heavenly Mother, the Woman Clothed with the Sun, who is now gathering all her little children into her army, drawn up for battle.
> Now that you are coming to the most painful and bloody years of this great struggle, I have intervened personally in order to form for myself my cohort through the Marian Movement of Priests, which is my work…” (297c-i, Nov. 9, 1984)

http://www.mmp-usa.net/spirituality/

> **"IN THE END MY IMMACULATE HEART WILL TRIUMPH." But, it will Triumph with all the faithfuls who are united with the Pope & Church Magisterium."**

Comment: @Ken Graham, I am asking you what are the mistakes of Fr.Gobbi can you provide a link, as far as I know the Church never mentioned any mistakes officially or do you have official link to substantiate your statement;.My source are Church approved documents, Pope Leo XIII vision, Pope Paul VI, Arch.Sheen & Fr.Gobbi's book with 3 imprimatur, plus the sainthood of Fr.Gobbi's is on the way, no official Church statement condemning his book. It's in harmony with Pope Benedict XVI predictions of the future Church.

Comment: Prophecy does not necessarily involve faith and morals. “The Pastors of the Church have the duty and the right to be vigilant lest the faith and morals of the faithful be harmed by writings; and consequently, even to demand that the publication of writing concerning the faith and morals should be submitted to the Church’s approval, and also to condemn books and writings that attack faith or morals.” [What are “imprimatur” and “nihil obstat” in Catholic books?](http://catholicstraightanswers.com/what-are-imprimatur-and-nihil-obstat-in-catholic-book/)

Comment: You have not answered my question for clarification!, please substantiate your negative statement against Fr.Gobbi. can you give official link to Vatican pronouncement about his book that have 3 IMPRIMATUR of Bishops. Otherwise your negative statement is baseless.

Comment: "The CDF asks that the locutions **not** be presented as messages from Mary but as Fr. Gobbi’s own meditations, it is not unreasonable to put some stock in his "advice." ..."For starters, there was message 287 (one of Fr. Gobbi‘s alleged messages from our Lady). In it, our Lady contradicts Pope John Paul II and Sr. Lucia..." - [The Marian Movement of Priests: Is It Safe for Faithful Catholics?](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?recnum=4152)

Comment: Re CDF letter.No personal correspondence from any individual who works for the Holy See has the force of law or the force of a decree or directive "Only official documents that are issued by those with legislative or executive authority (whether ordinary or delegated) can have the force of a law or a general or individual decree. (Canons 29 -34) .your link can be answered in full here re the said contradictions "In defense of orthodoxy of MMP"; http://www.mmp-usa.net/in-defense-of-the-orthodoxy-of-the-marian-movement-of-priests-our-ladys-messages-and-fr-gobbi/

Comment: Nonsense, the Holy See has that authority!